# Как правильно сказать "3 фарад" или "3 фарада"?

Tags: склонение

Как правильно сказать "3 фарад" или "3 фарада"?

Answer (score 2):

[**фара́д**](https://file:///C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads/Farad-76396%20(1).html), **-а**; р. мн. -ов, счётн. ф. **фара́д** (единица электрич. ёмкости)
(Русское словесное ударение. — М.: ЭНАС. М.В. Зарва. 2001)

Правильно: 1 фарад, 3 фарада, 10 фарад.

*Фарад* относится к [единицам с нулевым окончанием в родительном падеже множественного числа](http://www.az-print.com/index.shtml?FAQ&HelpBook/h009) (п. 9.2.9). Это наименования мужского рода, оканчивающиеся на твердый согласный звук.
Например: ампер, ангстрем, ватт, вольт, герц, децибел, карат, кельвин, кулон, люкс, люмен, максвелл, ньютон, ом, парсек, радиан, резерфорд, рентген, эрг.

[Единицы мужского рода, имеющие нетерминологические бытовые соответствия и употребляемые в литературном языке, в род. падеже мн. ч. имеют окончание **-ов.**
Например: метров, дециметров, литров, оборотов в секунду, узлов, центнеров, часов (п.9.2.10).]

Answer (score 1):

В профессиональной среде говорят *исключительно* так: "3 фарад**ы**" - по ранее нормативному наименованию единицы ёмкости "**фарада**" (именит. падеж ж. р.). Формально же сейчас принят вариант *мужского* рода, "**фарад**", поэтому нормативно "**3 фарада**"; аналогично: "3 ампера" (но "*5 ампер*", "*5 фарад*" - правила склонения существительных здесь не действуют).